# LUKS detached header on RHEL 6

Tags: linux, luks, dm-crypt

Is there any version of `cryptsetup` which supports **LUKS detached header** on RHEL-6 ?

`cryptsetup` provides detached header support on RHEL-7 (*cryptsetup-1.4 onwards*) but not on RHEL-6. I tried building cryptsetup-1.7 source code on RHEL-6 but could see that there are kernel dependent files like `if_alg.h` which are not present on RHEL-6.

I need to know if there is any way to support detached header on RHEL-6 ?

Answer (score 1):

I copied `cryptsetup-1.7` source code to RHEL-6 and was able to build it successfully. It required `if_alg.h` which I copied from RHEL-7 system and installed `libgcrypt-devel`.